# Submit is not working for contact form which was embedded by AJAX

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, emails

I'm trying to add contact form with AJAX callback, called from another form. Form is embedding as well, but when I submit it only page is reloading and form doesn't send any data (in my case it's a contact form, and I can't see any created contact message in backoffice after submitting).

```
function somemodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['somefield']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'somemodule_form_conditional_ajax',
    'method' => 'html',
    'wrapper' => 'form-conditional-ajax-wrapper',
    'event' => 'change',
  ];
  $form['#suffix'] = '<div id="form-conditional-ajax-wrapper"></div>'  

}


function somemodule_form_conditional_ajax($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $output = [];
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $conditional_form_id = $values['somefield'][0]['value'];

  $contact_message = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('contact_message')
    ->create([
      'contact_form' => $conditional_form_id,
  ]);

  if (!is_null($contact_message) && $contact_message instanceof Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface) {
    $output = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($contact_message);
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue myself. Try this:

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

function somemodule_form_conditional_ajax($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $output = [];
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $conditional_form_id = $values['somefield'][0]['value'];

  $contact_message = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('contact_message')
    ->create([
      'contact_form' => $conditional_form_id,
  ]);

  if (!is_null($contact_message) && $contact_message instanceof Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface) {
    $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($contact_message);
    $output = render($form);

    $data = BubbleableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($form);
    $attachments = $data->getAttachments();
    $settings = '';
    if(!empty($attachments['drupalSettings'])) {
      $settings .= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(drupalSettings, ';
      $settings .= Json::encode($attachments['drupalSettings']);
      $settings .= ');</script>';
    }

    $output .= $settings;
  }

  return $output;
}
```

The only thing I'm unsure about is if the $output requires an array - what I've given you is a string. So it may not work.